# Slick 2.10-RC1, Scala 2.11.x, bypassing 22 arity limit with case class (heterogenous)

Tags: scala, slick, case-class, shapeless

I am having issues in mapping a Table that has > 22 columns specifically into a `case class`, assuming you have the following code

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver
import scala.slick.collection.heterogenous._
import syntax._
import shapeless.Generic

case class TwentyThreeCaseClass(
    val id:Option[Long],
    val one:String,
    val two:String,
    val three:String,
    val four:String,
    val five:String,
    val six:String,
    val seven:String,
    val eight:String,
    val nine:String,
    val ten:String,
    val eleven:String,
    val twelve:String,
    val thirteen:String,
    val fourteen:String,
    val fifteen:String,
    val sixteen:String,
    val seventeen:String,
    val eighteen:String,
    val nineteen:String,
    val twenty:String,
    val twentyOne:String,
    val twentyTwo:String,
    val twentyThree:String,
    val twentyFour:String
)

class TwentyThreeTable(tag:Tag) extends Table[TwentyThreeCaseClass](tag,"twenty_three_table") {
    def id = column[Long]("id",O.PrimaryKey,O.AutoInc)
    def one = column[String]("one")
    def two = column[String]("two")
    def three = column[String]("three")
    def four = column[String]("four")
    def five = column[String]("five")
    def six = column[String]("six")
    def seven = column[String]("seven")
    def eight = column[String]("eight")
    def nine = column[String]("nine")
    def ten = column[String]("ten")
    def eleven = column[String]("eleven")
    def twelve = column[String]("twelve")
    def thirteen = column[String]("thirteen")
    def fourteen = column[String]("fourteen")
    def fifteen = column[String]("fifteen")
    def sixteen = column[String]("sixteen")
    def seventeen = column[String]("seventeen")
    def eighteen = column[String]("eighteen")
    def nineteen = column[String]("nineteen")
    def twenty = column[String]("twenty")
    def twentyOne = column[String]("twentyOne")
    def twentyTwo = column[String]("twentyTwo")
    def twentyThree = column[String]("twentyThree")
    def twentyFour = column[String]("twentyFour")

    private def iso[L <: HList, M <: HList](l: L)
                                 (implicit iso: Generic.Aux[TwentyThreeCaseClass, M], eq: L =:= M): TwentyThreeCaseClass = iso.from(l)

    def * =
        id.? ::
        one ::
        two ::
        three ::
        four ::
        five ::
        six ::
        seven ::
        eight ::
        nine ::
        ten ::
        elven ::
        twelve ::
        thirteen ::
        fourteen ::
        fifteen ::
        sixteen ::
        seventeen ::
        eighteen ::
        nineteen ::
        twenty ::
        twentyOne ::
        twentyTwo ::
        twentyThree ::
        twentyFour ::
        HNil
        // Do stuff here to map to a case class

}
```

How exactly would you go about constructing/extracting the table into the `TwentyThreeCaseClass`. Example code is given on how to make a slick `Table` map to a HList, but code is not given on how to map a Table to a case class > 22 parameters via a `HList` (you can't use tuples, because the arity limit in Scala still applies for tuples, you can't make a tuple with more then twenty two elements)

The `iso` is there, because we use this generic iso code to map from a `HList` to a `case class` with the same shape in our shapeless code outside of slick, so theoretically speaking you should be able to use iso to construct the case class from the `HList`, i just have no idea how to use iso in the context of slick shapes

EDIT:
There is the same question asked on the slick github as an issue here https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/519#issuecomment-48327043

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out, its pretty ugly though since its not generic.

```
def * =
    (id.? ::
    one ::
    two ::
    three ::
    four ::
    five ::
    six ::
    seven ::
    eight ::
    nine ::
    ten ::
    elven ::
    twelve ::
    thirteen ::
    fourteen ::
    fifteen ::
    sixteen ::
    seventeen ::
    eighteen ::
    nineteen ::
    twenty ::
    twentyOne ::
    twentyTwo ::
    twentyThree ::
    twentyFour ::
    HNil).shaped <>
          ({case x => TwentyThreeCaseClass(
            x(0),
            x(1),
            x(2),
            x(3),
            x(4),
            x(5),
            x(6),
            x(7),
            x(8),
            x(9),
            x(10),
            x(11),
            x(12),
            x(13),
            x(14),
            x(15),
            x(16),
            x(17),
            x(18),
            x(19),
            x(20),
            x(21),
            x(22),
            x(23),
            x(24)
            )}, ({x:TwentyThreeCaseClass =>
            Option((
              x.id ::
              x.one ::
              x.two ::
              x.three ::
              x.four ::
              x.five ::
              x.six ::
              x.seven ::
              x.eight ::
              x.nine ::
              x.ten ::
              x.eleven ::
              x.twelve ::
              x.thirteen ::
              x.fourteen ::
              x.fifteen ::
              x.sixteen ::
              x.seventeen ::
              x.eighteen ::
              x.nineteen ::
              x.twenty ::
              x.twentyOne ::
              x.twentyTwo ::
              x.twentyThree ::
              x.twentyFour ::
              HNil
            ))
          }))
```

It turns out there are a few things

1. This has nothing to do with shapeless, Slick uses its own `HList` implementation (which has the exact same syntax as shapeless!)
2. As far as I am aware, Slick `HList` doesn't appear to have any generic methods for dealing with stuff like mapping to a `case class` (and going from a case class to a Slick `HLIst)
3. Eiher a library that converts Slick `Hlist` to a shapeless `HList` would be handy, or generic abilities for Slick `Hlist`. The former may be a better option because shapeless already does generic stuff much better than Slick, and it may be out of Slicks scope

Doing something like

```
def gen = Generic[TwentyThreeCaseClass]
...
.shaped <>
      ({case x => gen.from(x)}, {TwentyThreeCaseClass => Option(gen.to(x))})
```

Would be much more ideal

here is another example as well

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/214

Comment: You could shorten `x.apply(1)` to `x(1)`.

Comment: @mdedetrich Code like this really makes me question Slick as a viable option for real-world, database-heavy applications. It seems to create mess, and lacks a lot of required features (fetch-size/batch-size, optimistic/pessimistic locking, transaction propagation, etc...)