# (Viable) scala libraries for database-heavy applications

Tags: java, scala, jpa, slick

I am building a database heavy application in Scala and I'm doing some research to find a suitable library for the persistence layer. The most stable and bulletproof choice would be sticking with JPA but the application is a bit special in that arbitrary queries must be supported across tables some of which have >50 columns and doing this with Criteria is just too painful.

I would like to get some advice from more knowledgeable folk who have used Scala persistence libraries in real world projects. How do these compare? How do they solve the 22 field limit (which is solved in scala 2.11 but still affects at least Slick as far as I know). This point is vital for my use case and resolving to scary ugly hacks [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978042/slick-2-10-rc1-scala-2-11-x-bypassing-22-arity-limit-with-case-class-heteroge) is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried Querydsl? It's a typesafe jpa wrapper, and it provides a convinient scala api (http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.5.0/reference/html/ch02s09.html).
Defining jpa classes in scala is a bit ugly (and kind of breaks the functional style) but doable.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of querydsl which I regard as an alternative to Criteria. That's not quite what I'm after though. To be honest I don't care too much for query type safety. I'm leaning towards Anorm mostly for its flexibility.